# Logging each error on a new line php

Tags: php, string, string-concatenation

I need to log each error on a new line.

```
file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage() . \n, FILE_APPEND);
```

This works as intended except everything remains on the first line so my attempt to use \n appears incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative way:

```
file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should quote the `\n`.

```
file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage() . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Or use `PHP_EOL` constant.

```
file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: @Lake is right -- try to keep your code cross-OS compatible when possible.

Comment: I used EOL (though the author deleted the solution before I could accept it.)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes. See more about [string concatenation in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage() ."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Or for cross compatibly:

```
file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage() .PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```